# Solr performance (tomcat) - High load

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, solr

I'm relatively new to solr. I have a production site running on a VPS, but now I'm having serious load issues. I don't know where to start in order to get the load down...

**VPS specs (linode.com 512)**

- 512 MB RAM
- 4 CPU (1x priority)

Looks like my solr server (tomcat) is using a lot of CPU power

[image]

You can find my solrconfig.xml on http://pastebin.com/qdfi8Med
and my schema.xml on http://pastebin.com/rRusDP8b

I've tried to increaese the cache size, but this didn't do anything on the load. You can see the stats page below.

**EDIT - Because the screenshot was unclear, I took smaller screenshots if what (I think) is important.**

*Dismax query handler stats*

[image: Dismax query handler stats]

*Caches stats*
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Solr is quite resource-intensive. According to your screencaps, you are trying to handle 21 requests per second on a server with 512MB of RAM. Very simply, you might need to just throw more hardware at this problem to get it under control.

Comment: Isn't it possible to tweak it a bit? I try to get the maximum out of my hardware. I hope there are ways to optimise this.

Comment: I adjusted JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx420M -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/solr/logging.properties", maybe this can be tweaked? Or some things in solrConfig/Caches?

Answer (score 0):

First, 512MB is just a bit too little to run Solr 3.6 with Tomcat, Solr 4.0 may crash.
I Used to run Solr 4.0 on EC2 micro, it has 613 MB ram. it was not enough to run a small Solr site (5-10 req/s)

To Run Solr safely, you will need the 1GB linode. But I do recommend a 2GB machine to run SOLR smoothly.

On my 1.6GB SMall EC2 Server, I set SOLR max memory to 1.2GB, and leave the remaining 400MB for OS caching and other small services like monit, munin, ssh, apt-get, rsync, backups, etc.

this is my JAVA_OPTS that I set on my .bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"
export SOLR_HOME="/mnt/Solr/Home"
export CATALINA_HOME="/mnt/Tomcat/Home"
export LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/dev/null"
unset JAVA_OPTS
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1200m -Xmx1200m -server -d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=200m"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/mnt/Solr/Home"
```

Amazon EC2 CPU is very low compared to Linode, but I have great performance with it since Solr uses almost no CPU but a lot of ram... 
you could go with EC2 medium for a large Solr Server.

PS. Also I noticed your Screenshot that you have the kswapd0 process that recorded a lot of CPU IO time. I have that issue with linode and it was because of an outdated kernel. you should reboot your maching with a newer kernel.

Comment: If you insist on running solr on a 512MB machine try these settings:


-Xms200m -Xmx360m -server -d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=80m